# Axios Request Not Triggered in Mapbox GL JS Application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, axios, mapbox

**Description:**

I'm a (very) junior dev. working on a Mapbox GL JS application that aims to fetch data from a local API, which in turn retrieves data from a MongoDB database, using Axios. The goal is to display markers on a map based on the MongoDB data. However, I've encountered an issue where the Axios request doesn't seem to be triggered, and as a result, no data is displayed on the map.

**Problem:**

The specific problem I'm facing is that the Axios request to `http://localhost:3000/api/projects` does not seem to be making the call to the API, which is responsible for retrieving data from a MongoDB database. Despite extensive troubleshooting, adding extensive console.log, ensuring that the API endpoint is valid and the server is running, the request doesn't occur - i.e. **isn't listed in the network tab of my developer tools**.

**Context:**

I'm developing a Mapbox GL JS application deployed on Heroku, and I have a Node.js backend server running locally on `http://localhost:3000`. The application is supposed to fetch project data from the local server, which, in turn, retrieves this data from a MongoDB database, and then display markers on a map using Mapbox GL JS.

**Code:**

Here is the relevant portion of my `map.js` code where the Axios request is made:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    console.log('DOMContentLoaded event fired');

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MYMAPBOXACCESSTOKEN';
    
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [20, 1.5],
        zoom: 0,
    });

try {
    // Make a request to the back-end API to fetch project data
    console.log('Making API request...');
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/projects');
    console.log('Received project data:', response.data);

    // Create a marker for each project (example data)
    response.data.forEach(project => {
        const {location, coordinates} = project;
        console.log('Project Location:', location);
        console.log('Project Coordinates:', coordinates);

    // Create a marker for each project
        const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
            .setLngLat([parseFloat(coordinates.lng), parseFloat(coordinates.lat)])
            .addTo(map);
        console.log('Marker added:', marker);
        });
    } catch(error) {
        console.error('Error fetching project data:', error);
    }
});
```

**Error Messages:**

There are no error messages in the console related to the Axios request.
This is my console output for the HTML file:

DOMContentLoaded event fired

Making API request...

**Environment:**

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Browser: Google Chrome (Version 100.0.0)
- Node.js Version: 14.17.0
- Libraries and Dependencies: Axios 0.24.0, Mapbox GL JS 2.4.0, Cors 2.8.5, Mongodb 5.7.0

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you so much!

**Attempts to Solve:**

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- Checked the Axios import and dependencies.
- Verified the server is running on `http://localhost:3000`.
- Ensured the API endpoint is correct and functional.
- Checked for any potential conflicts with other scripts.
- Cleared browser cache, disinstalled extensions, updated the browser.
- Tried another browser.
- Configured CORS
- Checked for typos hundred of times.
- Tried running Node.js on an alternative port.
- I have tried to add `import axios from 'axios'` on top of my file. This makes the map completely disappear. I've cleared all of my dependencies and reinstalled them one by one. The map is still not showing up, therefore I'm certain that the issue is related to axios.

**Expected Behavior:**

I expect the Axios request to `http://localhost:3000/api/projects` to be triggered, and the project data to be displayed as markers on the Mapbox map.

Comment: You might want to add, which ones of the console logs in your code actually get triggered; i.e. provide the entire output in the console instead of just stating that there are no errors.

Comment: Do you see the request being made in the browser tools network panel?